# Let $E$ be a Riesz space. Show that if $f_n \to f$, then $f_{n_k} \to f$ for every subsequence $(f_{n_k}:k=1,2,\ldots)$ such that $n_1<n_2<\cdots$.

Tags: solution-verification, vector-lattices

Let $E$ be a Riesz space. Show that if $f_n \to f$, then $f_{n_k} \to f$ for every subsequence $(f_{n_k}:k=1,2,\ldots)$ such that $n_1<n_2<\cdots$.

The reference/book was I used is "Introduction to Operator Theory in Riesz Space (1997), by Adriaan C. Zaanen" in the chapter $4$: subchapter $10$. Given below are some basic definitions.

**Definition.**
Let $E$ be a Riesz space. The sequence $(f_n: n=1,2,\ldots)$ in $E$ is said to be *increasing* if $f_1 \le f_2 \le \cdots$ and *decreasing* if $f_1 \ge f_2 \ge \cdots$, which are denoted by $f_n \uparrow$ and $f_n \downarrow$, respectively.
If $f_n \uparrow$ and $f=\sup f_n$ exists in $E$, we write $f_n \uparrow f$. Similarly,
if $f_n \downarrow$ and $f=\inf f_n$ exists in $E$, we write $f_n \downarrow f$.
If $f_n \uparrow f$ or $f_n \downarrow f$, we say that $f_n$ *converges monotonely* to $f$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

**Definition.** The sequence $(f_n:n=1,2,\ldots)$ in a Riesz space $E$ is said to *converge in order* to $f$ if there exists a sequence $p_n \downarrow 0$ such that $|f-f_n| \le p_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

**Attempt:**
Let $f_n \to f$. By definition, there exists a sequence $(p_n)$ with $p_n \downarrow 0$ such that $|f-f_n| \le p_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. So, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, we have
\begin{align*}
|f-f_n| \le p_n \iff f-p_n \le f_n \le f+p_n. \qquad (1)
\end{align*}
Now, let $(f_{n_k}:k=1,2,\ldots)$ be a subsequence of $(f_n)$ such that $n_1<n_2<\cdots$.
It's clear that $f_{n_k} \in (f_n)$, for any fixed positive integer $n_k$ and for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Hence, $f_{n_k}$ must satisfy $(1)$. That is,
\begin{align*}
f-p_{n_k} \le f_{n_k} \le f+p_{n_k} \iff |f-f_{n_k}| \le p_{n_k}.
\end{align*}
Next, it's also clear that $p_{n_k} \in (p_n)$ for any fixed positive integer $n_k$ and for any $n \in \Bbb N$. Now, since $p_n \downarrow 0$, then $p_{n_k} \downarrow 0$.
Hence, we found a sequence $(p_{n_k})$ with $p_{n_k} \downarrow 0$ such that $|f-f_{n_k}| \le p_{n_k}$, for all $k \in \Bbb N$. Thus, $f_{n_k} \to f$, by definition. Q.E.D.

Does the above approach correct? If no, how to approach the solution of the given problem?
Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the comment. Do you have any other idea to approach it with a simpler approach than above, Sir?

Comment: What you have done is quite natural and it cannot be simplified.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy OK, Sir. Thanks for your correction. Now, the problem is solved. :D